# MegaRAID SAS 8208XLP

Tags: debian, raid, sas, lsi, megaraid

I'm just wondering whether anyone knows if I can use a Debian distro with the MegaRAID SAS 8208XLP controller. Currently at the moment LSI only supply drivers/support for RHEL/CentOS but I was wondering if anybody knew if there were other drivers so the RAID controller can work with other distributions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some resources

http://www.how2forge.info/megacli-for-debian-ubuntu

http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/DebianPackages

http://ftzdomino.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/some-useful-megacli-commands.html

Megacli is the management software for LSI SAS Raid controllers.

Downloading:
It can be obtained from the support & downloads tab at the following url (account is required)
http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/MegaRAIDSAS9280-8e.aspx

Readme is here:
http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/MegaRAID%20Common%20Files/8.02.16_MegaCLI.txt

```
$ unzip -l ./8.02.16_MegaCLI.zip
Archive:  ./8.02.16_MegaCLI.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    23852  2011-08-12 10:13   8.02.16_MegaCLI.txt
  2836620  2011-07-04 12:06   LINUX/MegaCliLin.zip
     2748  2011-07-04 12:06   LINUX/readme.txt
        0  2011-08-12 00:23   LINUX/
... ... ...
 35329519                     20 files

$ unzip -d ./megacli 8.02.16_MegaCLI.zip
Archive:  8.02.16_MegaCLI.zip
  inflating: ./megacli/8.02.16_MegaCLI.txt  
  inflating: ./megacli/LINUX/readme.txt

$ cd megacli/LINUX
Archive:  MegaCliLin.zip
  inflating: MegaCli-8.02.16-1.i386.rpm  
  inflating: Lib_Utils-1.00-09.noarch.rpm

$ apt-get install rpm2cpio

$ rpm2cpio MegaCli-8.02.16-1.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv
./opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli
./opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64
9502 blocks
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely going to work, as there is a [MegaRAID SAS driver](http://wiki.debian.org/LinuxRaidForAdmins#megaraid_sas) in the Debian kernel. You will need additional tools (MegaCLI) from [here](http://kb.lsi.com/Download15865.aspx) to maintain it from the running system.

That they support only RHEL etc. just mean that they won't guarantee that the hardware is going to work on Debian and that they don't help you get it running. Usually it should work though.